# Seeking comparison table for different regexes

Tags: regex, comparison

I use vim, sed, bash and Perl. Each has somewhat different regex syntax.  I just spent time finding that I need to escape the curly parens in sed, but not in BASH (when using them as counter elements).  Grrr.

Can anybody point me to a table that summarizes the differences between the different regex parsers in these 4 environments.

TIA

Comment: In addition to these answers: Mastering regular expressions is an excellent resource! http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html - scroll down a bit.

Bash uses posix regexes. Sed and vim (which uses ed) use what are listed as "GNU BRE", although this depends on what flags you pass.

Answer (score 1):

Jan Goyvaerts.'s site [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html) has a listing of popular regex engines and which options they support.